# How do i make a Java program write out numbers in a 7 number interval?

Tags: java, int, max, intervals, min

I have to make a program that prints out all numbers between a given min and max point.The printed numbers need to be in a 7 number interval so it starts with 26 then 33 then 40 and so on up to 112.

The method looks like this:

```
    public void series7(int min, int max)
    {

    }
```

And the main method like this:

```
    public void exerciceE(Prog1 prog1) 
    {
    System.out.println("TEST of: series7");
    prog1.series7(26, 112);
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Have you studied `for` loops yet?

Comment: Have you tried running the code ?If yes, please be specific about what issue you are facing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use for loop

```
for(int i=min;i<=max;i+=7)
       System.out.print(i+" ");
```

output

```
26 33 40 47 54 61 68 75 82 89 96 103 110
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Bk3Rqb)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void series7(int min, int max)
{
    if (min <= max) {
        System.out.println(min);
        series7(min + 7, max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly haven't even attempted to try this yourself. You should always upload any code you've attempted along with the issue you're having.

That being said:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = 10; 
    int end   = 30;
    series7(start, end);
}

public static void series7(int start, int end){
    for( int i = start; i <= end; i = i + 7){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it myself but the code didn't work so i removed it, maybe i should have kept it.

Comment: In the future you should post the code you've tried rather than getting other people to come up with the implementation for you.